# DCPROMO Error: DNS name does not exist."(error code 0x0000232B RCODE NAME ERROR

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

Our schools has two domain controllers running Server 2008. One DC experienced issues forcing us to demote the system. We are now trying to run DCPROMO and experience the below error.

> The domain name CAMPUS might be a NetBIOS domain name.  If this is the
>   case, verify that the domain name is properly registered with WINS.
>
> If you are certain that the name is not a NetBIOS domain name, then
>   the following information can help you troubleshoot your DNS
>   configuration.
>
> The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service
>   location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory
>   Domain Controller for domain CAMPUS:
>
> The error was: "DNS name does not exist." (error code 0x0000232B
>   RCODE_NAME_ERROR)
>
> The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.CAMPUS
>
> Common causes of this error include the following:
>
> - The DNS SRV records required to locate a AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS. These records are registered with a DNS server
>     automatically when a AD DC is added to a domain. They are updated by
>     the AD DC at set intervals. This computer is configured to use DNS
>     servers with the following IP addresses:
>
> 192.168.1.2
>
> - One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child zone:
>
> CAMPUS . (the root zone)
>
> For information about correcting this problem, click Help.

1. DNS on the NIC points directly to the working DNS, which also serves as our current DC (192.168.1.2).
2. When pinging the DNS by IP, we receive a reply. When pinging the DC computer name, we receive an IPV6 response, but the correct IP can be seen when adding -4 to the end of the ping.
3. Clients (more than 40) are using the DC just fine without any issues
4. We can ping campus.school.local and just campus on both servers. The working DC responds fine, along with clients. However, the other cannot resolve the domain.
5. We also tried adding our domain info to the DNS suffix for problem DC with no luck.
6. Rebuilding our domain just is not an option with hundreds of accounts at stake.

I look forward to any help here, I am stumped.

Comment: Did you try to query your DNS for SRV record `_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.CAMPUS`, using `nslookup` ?

Comment: @krisFR I end up receiving the following error when running that command. Of course, it works from other clients including the DC. Btw, the server is pointing to the DC for DNS too. 'Address:  ::1 *** UnKnown can't find _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.CAMPUS: Non-existent domain'